# From their perspective vs from their perspectives

Tags: grammar

The topic sums it up.
Imagine we are discussing the points of view(s) of a population.

I often say "From their perspective, minimum wage is a good thing."
However, if they all have  perspective, should the correct form not be, "From their perspectives, minimum wage is a good thing."

Notice that although there is only one perspective, each of them has this perspective, thus resulting in the same, but many of the same perspective. Would both of these work?

Comment: population, perspective; individuals, perspectives OR individual, perspective.

Comment: As long as they all have the same perspective, use "perspective".

Comment: Normally the singular form would be used, but there's no law requiring it.  In some contexts the plural would be preferred because it better conveys the sense that multiple individuals are involved.

Comment: There are differing opinions on minimum wage, but if "minimum wage is a good thing," that's one opinion, one perspective.

Answer (score -1):

Their perspective: each of them has only one perspective.

Their perspectives: each or some of them has more than one perspective.